# really simple sybase sql function won't work

Tags: sql, t-sql, sybase, sql-function

I was wondering why this simple sql function won't work?

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.getTableCounts (@STREAM_ID nvarchar(10))
RETURNS table
AS RETURN ( select 1 as 'one', 2 as 'two');
```

When I run it in qwerybuilder I get two error messages:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'table' (for line 2)
```

and

```
Incorrect syntax near ',' (for line 3)
```

I don't understand how this is incorrect syntax.  Does anyone see why this is an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to ASE's [Reference manual](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36272.1570/html/commands/CHDEDGJI.htm) You can only return a scalar expression:

```
create function [ owner_name. ] function_name 
    [ ( @parameter_name [as] parameter_datatype [ = default ]
        [ ,...n ] ) ] 
    returns return_datatype
    [ with recompile]
    as 
    [begin]
    function_body 
    return scalar_expression
    [end]
```

So you can't use `table` as data type.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike Microsoft SQL Server, in Sybase if you need table as a result type you don't use a function but a stored procedure. In your case the definition of the procedure (written in Watcom-SQL) will look like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getTableCounts(@STREAM_ID NVARCHAR(10))
RESULT(one INT, two INT)
BEGIN
  SELECT 1 AS one, 2 AS two;
END;
```

However this option is not supported by Transact-SQL dialect in Sybase.